# My function won't run

Tags: javascript

My function professorOpen will not start up again thought it is called. I used an alert to see if the problem was in the onclick, but the alert worked, so it must be a problem with the call. I know the images won't show, but that doesn't matter.  Thanks for the help!

```js
var gameContainer = document.getElementById("game-container");

var gender;

var speechBox = document.createElement("DIV");
 speechBox.id = "speech-box";
 var speechP = document.createElement("P");
  speechP.id = "speech-p"
  var speech = document.createTextNode("");
 var speechNum = 0;
 var text = true;

function preProfessorOpen() {
 var startButton = document.getElementById("start-button");
 gameContainer.removeChild(startButton);
 document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(index/src/img/professor.png)";
 gameContainer.appendChild(speechBox);
  speechBox.appendChild(speechP);
  speechP.innerHTML = "Welcome to the world of Pok&eacute;mon, clod!";
 speechBox.onclick = function(){professorOpen();}
  function professorOpen() {
   speechNum++;
   switch(speechNum) {
    case 1:
     speech = "I am Yellow Diamond &ndash; reduced to introducing Pok&eacute;mon Spin-Offs.";
     break;
    case 2:
     speech = "This world of clods is widely inhabited by creatures known as Pok&eacute;mon.";
     break;
    case 3:
     speech = "These mysterious creature can be found in every corner of this world...";
     break;
    case 4:
     speech = "Some run across the plains, others fly through the skies, and others yet swim deep in the oceans...";
     break;
    case 5:
     speech = "Clods live together with these Pok&eacute;mon, lending their little strength to one another to live and prosper.";
     break;
    case 6:
     speech = "Let's get started with some quick questions...<br>Are you a boy? Or are you a girl?<br>(Probably a boy if Alex shared this with you.)";
     break;
    case 7:
     speechBox.onclick = ""
     speechBox.innerHTML = '<p id="male">Boy</p> \
                <p id="female">Girl</p>'
          document.getElementById("male").onclick = function(){gender = "boy"; speechNum++; professorOpen(); return;}
          document.getElementById("female").onclick = function(){gender = "girl"; speechNum++; professorOpen(); return;}
     break;
    case 8:
     speechBox.innerHTML = "";
     speechBox.appendChild(speechP);
     speech = "So, you're a " + gender + "? \
       <br> \
       <span id='yes-p'>Yep!</span> \
       <span id='no-p'>No, obviously.</span>";
        document.getElementById("yes-p").onclick = function(){professorOpen(); return;}
        document.getElementById("no-p").onclick = function(){speechNum = 6; professorOpen(); return;}
   }
    if(text){speechP.innerHTML = speech;}
    text = true;
  }           //professOpen Func End
}             //preProfessOpen Func End
```

```css
body {
 background-color:black;
 background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:300px 700px; background-position:center top;
}
#game-container{
 width:800px; height:700px;
 border:1px solid white;
 margin:0 auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 padding:0;
}

#start-button{
 width:100px; height:40px;
 position:relative; top:330px; left:350px;
 background-color:red;
 border:1px solid white; border-bottom-width:2px; border-top-width:0px;
 font-size:125%;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#start-button:hover{
 color:white;
}
#logo{
 width:100%; height:300px;
 position:relative;
 z-index:3;
}
#sub-logo{
 text-shadow: 1px 0 5px white, -1px 0 5px white, 0 1px 5px white, 0 -1px 5px white;
 color:#FEFF00;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:50px;
 position:relative; bottom:70px; left:15px;
 z-index:2;
}
#sub-logo-img{
 width:550px; height:405px;
 margin:auto;
 position:relative; left:140px; bottom:170px;
 z-index:1;
}

#speech-box{
 width:60%; height:100px;
 background-color:white;
 color:black;
 font-size:125%;
 border:1px solid #999999; border-radius:20px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0 10px;
 opacity:.8;
 position:relative; bottom:10px; top:600px;
 cursor:pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout:none;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -khtml-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select:none;
  user-select:none;
}
.main-menu-box-pic{
 width:20px; height:20px;
 float:right;
 position:relative; bottom:3px;
}
#male{color:#0000FF; margin-bottom:0;}
#female{color:#FF0066; margin-top:10px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <title>Game</title>
 <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
 <meta name="author" content="Some Nerd.">
 <link rel="icon" href="index/src/img/favicon.ico">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index/src/style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div id="game-container">
  <button id="start-button" onclick="preProfessorOpen()">Start</button>
 </div>
 <script src="index/src/src.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't paste everything here & say it doesn't work. Be specific.

Comment: Are you sure preProfessorOpen is getting called? Add console.log("preProfessorOpen invoked") or something to debug instead of an alert. See the log on the browser's console. F12 on FireFox and Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the callback:

```
function(){gender = "boy"; speechNum++; professorOpen(); return;}
                           ^ no need to increment
```

`professorOpen` already increments speechNum, so don't need to increment before calling.

I've taken them out and the game works fine, I've added another line of speech after so you can see it works.

```js
var gameContainer = document.getElementById("game-container");

var gender;

var speechBox = document.createElement("DIV");
speechBox.id = "speech-box";
var speechP = document.createElement("P");
speechP.id = "speech-p"
var speech = document.createTextNode("");
var speechNum = 0;
var text = true;

function preProfessorOpen() {
    var startButton = document.getElementById("start-button");
    gameContainer.removeChild(startButton);
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(index/src/img/professor.png)";
    gameContainer.appendChild(speechBox);
    speechBox.appendChild(speechP);
    speechP.innerHTML = "Welcome to the world of Pok&eacute;mon, clod!";
    speechBox.onclick = function() {
      professorOpen();
    }

    function professorOpen() {

        speechNum++;
        switch (speechNum) {
          case 1:
            speech = "I am Yellow Diamond &ndash; reduced to introducing Pok&eacute;mon Spin-Offs.";
            break;
          case 2:
            speech = "This world of clods is widely inhabited by creatures known as Pok&eacute;mon.";
            break;
          case 3:
            speech = "These mysterious creature can be found in every corner of this world...";
            break;
          case 4:
            speech = "Some run across the plains, others fly through the skies, and others yet swim deep in the oceans...";
            break;
          case 5:
            speech = "Clods live together with these Pok&eacute;mon, lending their little strength to one another to live and prosper.";
            break;
          case 6:
            speech = "Let's get started with some quick questions...<br>Are you a boy? Or are you a girl?<br>(Probably a boy if Alex shared this with you.)";
            break;
          case 7:
            speechBox.onclick = ""
            speechBox.innerHTML = '<p id="male">Boy</p> \
                <p id="female">Girl</p>'
            document.getElementById("male").onclick = function() {
              gender = "boy";
              professorOpen();
              return;
            }
            document.getElementById("female").onclick = function() {
              gender = "girl";
              professorOpen();
              return;
            }
            break;
          case 8:
            speechBox.innerHTML = "So, you're a " + gender + "? \
       <br> \
       <span id='yes-p'>Yep!</span> \
       <span id='no-p'>No, obviously.</span>";
            document.getElementById("yes-p").onclick = function() {
              professorOpen();
              return;
            };
            document.getElementById("no-p").onclick = function() {
              speechNum = 6;
              professorOpen();
              return;
            };
            break;

          case 9:
            speechBox.innerHTML = "Next Line of Speech";
            break;
        }
        if (text) {
          speechP.innerHTML = speech;
        }
        text = true;
      } //professOpen Func End
  } //preProfessOpen Func End
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 300px 700px;
  background-position: center top;
}
#game-container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
#start-button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: 330px;
  left: 350px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  font-size: 125%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#start-button:hover {
  color: white;
}
#logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
#sub-logo {
  text-shadow: 1px 0 5px white, -1px 0 5px white, 0 1px 5px white, 0 -1px 5px white;
  color: #FEFF00;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 70px;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#sub-logo-img {
  width: 550px;
  height: 405px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 140px;
  bottom: 170px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#speech-box {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 125%;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  opacity: .8;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
  top: 600px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.main-menu-box-pic {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 3px;
}
#male {
  color: #0000FF;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#female {
  color: #FF0066;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>Game</title>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="author" content="Some Nerd.">
  <link rel="icon" href="index/src/img/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index/src/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="game-container">
    <button id="start-button" onclick="preProfessorOpen()">Start</button>
  </div>
  <script src="index/src/src.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you add anything else? When I do this with my full code (which should not affect this), the next line is once again "Let's get started with..." Then it stops changing at all.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention I also changed the beginning of case 8, in your code you had speechBox.appendChild, I used `speechBox.innerHTML =` directly.

Comment: You have to set it directly because you're adding click listeners for the yes/no confirms.

Comment: Thank you. It worked flawlessly.  I think innerHTML is easier than the way I was doing it, so I might use that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Function `professorOpen` is only declared when the function `preProfessorOpen` is executed. Are you always running `pre` before the actual `professorOpen`?

Edit: In order to have a "run once" sort of function, you could easily use a conditional.

```
var preRan = false;

function preProfessorOpen(){
  if( preRan ) return;

  // Scary code that should only be executed once here...

  preRan = true;
}

function professorOpen() {
  // We only want to run this fn if pre already ran
  if( !preRan ) return;

  // Your code for professorOpen here
}
```

Generally speaking, declaring functions inside other functions (like in your case) is pretty bad practice. You'll want to declare all your functions right away, so that this kind of thing does not happen -- and you can control their execution with statements akin to the above.

Comment: I use _pre_ in order to keep _speechP_ from being appended more than once.  Is there a better way?

Comment: My mind is blown. Thank you. Give me a sec to try it.

Comment: OK. I tried keeping the functions together and using the conditional, but, when I do, the original message "Welcome to..." appears again. **Then**, the correct message appears (after a click).  I have issues.